# Maximizing score by scheduling tasks

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, sorting

So we have a timeline of T days in which some tasks have to be performed.
Every task has a penalty score. If the task is not performed in the given timeline , it's score adds up in the final penalty score. Every task can be performed **only** after it's given starting time.

The input will be given in the format:

T

Score Quantity_of_task  Starting_time

For eg :

T = 10

140 5 4

This means that 5 tasks with penalty score 140 have to be performed from 4th day onwards.
You can perform at most 1 task on a particular day.

The goal is to minimize the final penalty score.

What I tried to do:

```
Example - 
T = 10

Input size = 5

150 4 1                                                                     
120 4 3                                                                                                                                                 
200 2 7                                                                                                                                                                                                
100 10 5                                                                                                                                                                              
50 5 1
```

I sorted the list according to the penalty score , and **greedily** assigned the tasks with high penalty score to their corresponding days,i.e

2 tasks with highest score 200 are assigned to days 7 and 8

4 tasks with next highest score 150 are assigned to 1,2,3,4 days

4 tasks with next highest score 120 are assigned to 5,6,9,10 days

which gives the schedule as
150 150 150 150 120 120 200 200 120 120

Left out tasks:

10 tasks with 100 score = 1000 penalty
5 tasks with 50 score = 250 penalty

Final penalty = 1250.

This requires O(T * input_size). Is there a more elegant and optimized way of doing it?

Both input size and T have a constraint of 10^5.

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't use unrelated tags. If you decide to ask this with a specific example implementation, add your code and the *exact* language tag.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Ohh okay , got it.

Comment: Just adding: this might actually be a good idea. If you show code, it helps to get a better idea about what you want (it's easier to get for many than an abstract description) **and** with the correct tag, your question will be seen by many people familiar with the language you chose.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Hi Felix,the aim of this question is to help find a better algorithm, I still have'nt coded my approach yet, because I know it is not an 
 optimum solution. I want help in finding a better way of solving the problem.

Comment: Why do you think it's *not optimal*? The solution should be the minimum possible this way. As for how you implement that, that's another story...

Comment: @FelixPalmen As mentioned in the problem, the complexity would turn out to be O(T * input_size) , i.e O(10^10) , which is obviously not good enough. Can you suggest a good implementation of this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store the available days in an ordered set, then you can perform your algorithm much faster.

For example, C++ provides an ordered set with a [lower_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/lower_bound/) method that will find in O(logn) time the first available day after the starting time.

Overall this should give an O(nlogn) algorithm where n = T+input_size.

For example, I suspect that when you have your 4 tasks of penalty 120 to assign from day 3 onwards, your current code will loop over days 3,4,5,etc. until you find a day that has not been assigned.   You can now replace this O(n) loop with a single O(logn) call to lower_bound to find the first unassigned day.  When you greedily assign the days, you should also remove them from the set so they won't be assigned twice.

Note that there are only T days so there will be at most T day assignments.  For example, suppose all tasks have starting time 1, and quantity T.  Then the first task will take O(Tlogn) time to assign, but all subsequent tasks will only need a single call to lower_bound (because there are no days left to assign), so will take O(logn) each.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for replying , can you please elaborate a bit on this?

Comment: Added an example

Comment: but still a loop will be required to actually assign the task to a day. For eg after finding the first unassigned day for 120 , i.e 5 , I wil need to loop for 5 and 6 to assign them 120 , skip over 7 and 8 and then again assign 9 and 10.
What I aim is to somehow eliminate the actual assigning....

Comment: Are you sure this won't be fast enough already?  Note there will be at most 10^5 assignments because this is the total number of days.

Comment: There will be an outer loop iterating over the sorted scores so it will be of input_size, then for every score I will have to loop for some x (say) < T. (x being the length between first unassigned day to some day <=T).
This in worst case could go O(input_size^2)  if all tasks have starting time = 1 and quantity = T

Comment: I've added another example for this case.  Note that the first task will be slow, but all other tasks will be fast in your example.

Comment: Hi Peter, i don't think this approach would work because lower bound will not work as the lower_bound method works only for sorted lists , but herre the days are randomly assigned . For eg : 150 150 150 150 __ __ 200 200 __ __ , let this be the list when 120 is to be assigned and assume that start time of 120 is 1. Now I cannot apply lower_bound to find available position for 120

Comment: In your example, the set will contain the days that are still to be assigned in sorted order.  Here the days will be {5,6,9,10} as these are the only days left.  With a start time of 1, the lower_bound call will return the first unassigned day, namely 5.

Comment: Maintaining the set of unassigned days will itself require removal of multiple days as soon as they get assigned , which in turn would still require a loop?

Comment: It does require a loop, but we have a total of at most 10^5 iterations of this loop across all tasks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149257/discussion-between-ravi-kishan-and-peter-de-rivaz).